# Is r8168 installer in ubuntu software center secure and working?

Tags: drivers, internet, ethernet, realtek

Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06) that is what Ethernet Card I have. I have a question:
I am using 14.10 and I have found issue with r8169 and NVIDIA bin 331.89 uncompability. Might installing that r8168 package in Ubuntu Software center help? And if so, what does it exactly requiere to do so I can install it?

Answer (score 0):

Personal speaking, I've made the experience that `r8168` works better on various RTL81XX chips than `r8169`

Packages installed using APT automatically satisfy all dependencies. So everything required is installed when the package is being installed.

You need, however, prevent `r8169` from being loaded after r8168 is installed. The DKMS installation script of `r8168` unloads `r8169`, but it may be reloaded after a reboot.   Thus, open the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` (or create, if it doesn't exist) as root and append the line

```
blacklist r8169
```

to prevent the module to be loaded again. Ensure that there's a new line at the end of the file, then save and quit.

You can check whether the driver was loaded correctly using `lsmod | grep r8168`. If it doesn't return anything, the driver isn't loaded. In this case you can load it with `sudo modprobe r8168` after you installed it. If it lists the driver module, it's loaded. If you encounter problems with `r8168`, you can temporarily switch back to the other module by manually loading it: `sudo modprobe -r r8168 && sudo modprobe r8169`.

---

**IMPORTANT**: Note that the driver source on Realtek's website is more current than the one in Ubuntu's repositories. So you may want to download and compile it manually. You can obtain it [here](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2).

Comment: OK! Maybe someday it will help

Comment: Is that r8168 in software center working on Kernel 3.16? How do I uninstall it, if I have blacklisted r8169? Can it fix issue, when it makes uncompability with NVIDIA GeForce 331.x drivers?

Comment: If you blacklisted r8169, you can still manually load it with modprobe. The LAN driver doesn't interfere with your graphics card. I assume the version in the software center will work, but the one from Realtek's website may have some additional bugfixes etc.

Comment: If I install it, but it does not work, is it possible to remove it with apt-get purge r8168-dkms?

Comment: Every package is uninstallable like this. But first unload r8168 and load r8169 to ensure you're back online.

Comment: Oh... So `load [driver_name]` makes me use exact driver from aviable ones?

Comment: No, you have to use `sudo modprobe [driver_name]` to load it and `sudo modprobe -r [driver_name]` to unload it.